# Sub aggregation scripting with parameters taken from parent aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to use the `key` value of an aggregation bucket as a parameter in a sub-aggregation?

Having an index like:

```
{
    "id": 152,
    "description": "cool stuff",
    "datesWithTotal" : [
        {
            "date" : "2014-02-02T00:00:00",
            "total" : 47.2
        },
        {
            "date" : "2014-02-03T00:00:00",
            "total" : 51.2
        },
        {
            "date" : "2014-02-04T00:00:00",
            "total" : 56.4
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to perform a `date_histogram` aggregation with a sub-aggregation which will perform some operation based on the current `parentbucket.key` value

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "histo": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "datesWithTotal.date",
                "interval": "1d"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "script-test": {
                    "scripted_metric": {
                        "init_script": "_agg['sum'] = 0",
                        "map_script": "_agg.sum += (PARENTBUCKET.KEY == 'somevalue' ? 1 : 0)",
                        "combine_script": "return _agg.sum"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've already used some scripts in this way but each one was not using anything from the parent, just plain integer parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an ideea. I've tested it quickly but, for whatever  reason, is not outputting what I thought it should. Maybe it gives you some further ideas or you can make it work in a way I haven't been able to so far:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "histo": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "datesWithTotal.date",
        "interval": "1d"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "doesIncludeDate": {
          "terms": {
            "script": "new Date(doc[\"datesWithTotal.date\"].value).format(\"yyyy-MM-dd\")",
            "valueType": "string",
            "include": {
              "pattern": "2014-02-04"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "script-test": {
              "scripted_metric": {
                "init_script": "_agg['sum'] = 0",
                "map_script": "_agg.sum += 1",
                "combine_script": "return _agg.sum"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "doesNotIncludeDate": {
          "terms": {
            "script": "new Date(doc[\"datesWithTotal.date\"].value).format(\"yyyy-MM-dd\")",
            "valueType": "string",
            "exclude": {
              "pattern": "2014-02-04"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "script-test": {
              "scripted_metric": {
                "init_script": "_agg['sum'] = 0",
                "map_script": "_agg.sum += 0",
                "combine_script": "return _agg.sum"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is to use a `terms` aggregation with an `include` and another `terms` with an `exclude` to have buckets that match your parent bucket key or not. For those that match use your script with `_agg.sum += 1` for the other use `_agg.sum += 0`.

Of course, all of this is for a very specific script you have: a date is X or not. If the script is more complex, it won't be useful. And I don't think you can access the parent key from a script (or I haven't found a way to do it).